# How to limit items count in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I wanted to limit the items to 3 in `LazyColumn` in the below code,

```
@Composable
fun MessageList(messages: List<Message>) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(
            items = messages,
            key = { message ->
                // Return a stable + unique key for the item
                message.id
            }
        ) { message ->
            MessageRow(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you just want 3 items, then replace

```
items = messages
```

with

```
items = messages.take(3)
```